# Compute ROC curve for a competing risk model

Tags: survival-analysis

For my thesis, I computed a competing risk model to model the risk of COVID-19 death (failcode=1) while taking into account the survival and other-causes of death as competing events (cencode =0). Here is my code to compute the competing risk model:

```
library(cmprsk)

cov <- subset(training_cov,select=c("Sex",
                                      "Migrant.background","Living.situation","Education","Income","Age.groups"))


factor <- c("Age.groups","Sex","Migrant.background","Living.situation","Education","Income")

model_spec <- reformulate(paste0(paste(factor,collapse = "+")))

covariates_matrix <- model.matrix(
  model_spec,
  data=training_cov,
  contrasts.arg = lapply(cov[factor],contrasts)
)[,-1]

fit.cov <- crr(training_cov$time,training_cov$status_cov,covariates_matrix,failcode = 1,cencode = 0)
```

My training dataset (training_cov) is composed of 70% of the data and used to run that model.

I would like to compute a ROC curve to see the performance of the model on my testing dataset composed of 30% of the data.

**Do you know how is it possible to obtain probabilities and plot the ROC curve when using a survival object in a competing risk model?**

Many thanks ! :)

Comment: I think you need statistical consultation. An ROC curve is constructed by first building a score function and then plotting specificity vs 1-sensitivity.